# Meteor.loginWithPassword reporting failed login incorrectly

Tags: javascript, meteor

When I log in using Meteor.loginWithPassword (**with valid credentials**) the callback fires with a 403 (incorrect password) error. Then a second later, Meteor.user() populates as though no error was encountered.

```
'click #loginSubmit': (event) -> 
  Meteor.loginWithPassword $("#usernameInput").val(), $("#passwordInput").val(), (error) ->
    if error
      Meteor.call("addLogEntry","Login Failed callback","Debug",error)
      alert "User not found or incorrect password"
```

This is especially annoying as the user gets an error popup and then immidiately gets taken to the post login landing page..

It's worth mentioning that the above code has been working flawlessly for months.. Only recently has it started acting up.

Answer (score 0):

This was me being a bit silly. login button was submitting (inside a form) as well as me manually submitting. The double submit seems to be the cause. eliminated one. Problem goes away.